# Making a flipbook using turn4js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know what I'm missing but my code doesn't work as a magazine. I am using Turn4js plugin and it's my first time with this plugin.And I have searched a lot but can't find any appropriate solution.No idea what is missing.There is not much information given or any tutorial is there through which i can learn this.

Code:

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#flipbook{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

#flipbook .page{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#flipbook .page-wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective:2000px;
    -moz-perspective:2000px;
    perspective:2000px;
}

#flipbook .hard{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#flipbook .odd{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    
}

#flipbook .even{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.95, #fff), color-stop(1, #dadada));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Email as attachment</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/turn.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqtest.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="flipbook">
   <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
   <div class="hard"></div>
   <div> Page 1 </div>
   <div> Page 2 </div>
   <div> Page 3 </div>
   <div> Page 4 </div>
   <div class="hard"></div>
   <div class="hard"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
   $("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true
   });
  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with script link http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#flipbook{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

#flipbook .page{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#flipbook .page-wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective:2000px;
    -moz-perspective:2000px;
    perspective:2000px;
}

#flipbook .hard{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#flipbook .odd{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    
}

#flipbook .even{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.95, #fff), color-stop(1, #dadada));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(left, #fff 95%, #dadada 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Email as attachment</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqtest.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="flipbook">
   <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
   <div class="hard"></div>
   <div> Page 1 </div>
   <div> Page 2 </div>
   <div> Page 3 </div>
   <div> Page 4 </div>
   <div class="hard"></div>
   <div class="hard"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
   $("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true
   });
  </script>
 </body>
```